# Adding a space in the "draw coordinates" "decimal with suffix" in QGIS v2.18.7

Tags: qgis, print-composer, coordinate-system

I am using QGIS v2.18.7. In the Print Composer I have turned on the "Draw coodinates" option "Decimal with suffix" to add these to my map.

However, I need to add a space between the degrees symbol and the suffix.

For example, the default for "Decimal with suffix" is `10°S` while I would like (due to journal requirements) to have: `10° S`.

I see there is a custom option, but it I can't figure out how to get this output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the print composer, after having added a map and enable the grid display under `grids`-->`Draw grid`-->`Draw coordinates`, you can select the `custom` option to specify the formatting. To enter your particular specifications for the coordinates, you need to click on the greek letter e symbol (epsilon) on the right.

[image]

You would then make use of the `@grid_number` and `@grid_axis` variables. Let's remember that for each coordinate to be printed, the custom format function will be called. `@grid_number` contains the value (number) to be printed while `@grid_axis` indicates if it is on the x or y axis.
So, a negative value means South (for y) or West (for x). A positive means North or East.

The format function would start by displaying the absolute value with 2 decimals  (it's up to you) - if any -, then adds the space and degree sign. It then forks it logic depending on whether the function is called for the X or Y axis (written as a `case` statement for readability). For each case, it again forks it logic depending on whether it is a negative or positive value. Finally, for each of the 4 combination (axis + sign), it adds the N/S/E/W letter to the label to be returned.

```
abs(format_number( @grid_number ,2)) 
|| ' °' 
|| CASE 
    WHEN  @grid_axis = 'x' 
       THEN 
         IF (@grid_number > 0, 'E' , 'W')
       ELSE
           IF (@grid_number > 0, 'N' , 'S')
       END
```

[image: custom grid format]

Answer (score 1):

Although the [code provided by JGH](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/255900/159912) works perfectly, here is a minor change to omit the suffix when dealing with 0°.

```
abs(format_number( @grid_number ,2)) 
|| ' °' 
|| CASE 
    WHEN  @grid_axis = 'x' 
       THEN 
         IF(@grid_number=0, ' ' , IF (@grid_number > 0, 'E' , 'W')) 
       ELSE
           IF(@grid_number=0, ' ', IF (@grid_number > 0, 'N' , 'S'))

       END
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers by @JGH and @Gabriel Bragion didn't work for me because abs() refused to parse "0,00" (because comma is not a valid separator for a floating point number)

Reordering helps (first abs() then format_number()), as done below:

```
format_number( abs(@grid_number) ,2) 
|| ' °' 
|| CASE 
    WHEN  @grid_axis = 'x' 
       THEN 
         IF(@grid_number=0, ' ' , IF (@grid_number > 0, 'E' , 'W')) 
       ELSE
           IF(@grid_number=0, ' ', IF (@grid_number > 0, 'N' , 'S'))

       END
```