# Custom format for a grid with degrees, minutes, seconds with suffix using letter from another language

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, qgis-3, grids-graticules, internationalization

I am designing a map in French where West is "Ouest", and thus the map should read `45°23′67′′O` instead of `45°23′67′′W`. I am using a version of QGIS in English (update: in the French version of QGIS, the default option is `O`). I am currently using QGIS 2.18.11, but intend to switch to 3.0 soon.

1) Is there a way to change the longitude and latitude suffix to another language or just set a different letter?

2) Using the `custom` option, how can I get the minutes and the seconds?  I found an example [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255861/adding-a-space-in-the-draw-coordinates-decimal-with-suffix-in-qgis-v2-18-7) that gets me a decimal degrees version with my own suffix, but I would like to keep degrees, minutes, seconds format. If `@grid_number` is degrees... what is the equivalent for minutes and seconds?

```
abs(format_number( @grid_number ,2)) 
|| ' °' 
|| CASE 
    WHEN  @grid_axis = 'x' 
       THEN 
         IF (@grid_number > 0, 'E' , 'O')
       ELSE
           IF (@grid_number > 0, 'N' , 'S')
       END
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transforming decimal degrees to degrees-minutes-seconds requires some intermediate variables, so you would need to create a custom function to achieve what you want.

The way to do the conversion is taken from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579535/how-to-convert-dd-to-dms-in-python), and is enhanced with the proper formatting and french orientation letter.

Using the numbers from the screen shot at the bottom:

1. select a custom format
2. click the epsilon beside it
3. select the function editor tab
4. create a new file, name it `dd_to_dms_FR`
5. paste the code below in the right pane of the function editor
6. click load

then go back to the `Expression` tab and call the new function  `dd_to_dms_FR( @grid_number,@grid_axis )`

```py
"""
Define new functions using @qgsfunction. feature and parent must always be the
last args. Use args=-1 to pass a list of values as arguments
"""

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def dd_to_dms_FR(grid_number,grid_axis, feature, parent):
    degree_sign= u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'
    is_positive = grid_number >= 0

    if grid_axis == 'x' :
      letter = 'E' if is_positive else 'O'
    else :
      letter = 'N' if is_positive else 'S'

    dd = abs(grid_number)
    minutes,seconds = divmod(dd*3600,60)
    degrees,minutes = divmod(minutes,60)
    #Uncomment below to get negative values
    #degrees = degrees if is_positive else -degrees
    output =  "%s %s %s' %s '' %s"  %(int(degrees),degree_sign ,int(minutes),int(seconds),letter)
    #To pad with zero the minutes/seconds (ex: 45° 01' 02"), use the following line
    #output =  "%s %s %02d' %02d '' %s"  %(int(degrees),degree_sign ,int(minutes),int(seconds),letter)
    return output
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to keep a double zero for the minutes and seconds?  e.g. 45d00'00''

Comment: @user3386170 Yes, you can format the numbers as you want. See the edited code